# OTP Automatic verification Using ionic 3 and angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic3, one-time-password

This is what i have tried till now

```
    declare let SMS:any;

    ............

      watchSMS() {   

      SMS.startWatch(
       success => {
         let removeSmsListener = this.renderer.listen('document', 'onSMSArrive', (event) => {
           this.smsArived(event);
        });
       },
       error => {

       }
     );
}

     stopWatch(){
    SMS.stopWatch();
  }

  smsArived = (result: any) => { 
    console.log("SMS DATA 2" + this.generatedNumber);
    this.stopWatch();   
}
```

But I get an error SMS is not defined. I need to automatically verify the otp which i receive in the sms. I have tried various solutions but nothing turned up well. So I seek help from someone who knows how to do this functionality. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

After your imports:

```
declare var SMS:any;
```

Start watching for incoming sms / Stop watching for incoming sms

```
startWatch() {
    if(SMS) SMS.startWatch(function(){
        console.log('watching started');
    }, function(){
        console.log('failed to start watching');
    });
}

stopWatch() {
    if(SMS) SMS.stopWatch(function(){
        console.log('watching stopped');
    }, function(){
        console.log('failed to stop watching');
    });
}
```

Event listener:

```
document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', (event) => {
    let sms = event.data;
});
```